# IE Twitter Bootstrap input-group-addon issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created this form and it works in Fire Fox, Safari, Opera and Chrome but in Edge and I.E. there are some issues, the backgrounds of the form items change after the mouse pointer has left them and turn dark green a colour I can not find in my CSS anywhere. Sometimes only part of say the textarea changes color leaving me scratching my head as to how this could be happening.

I have included the code below, it is opperating with Bootstrap v3.3.1 and jQuery v1.11.2.

[image]

HTML:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-name">Name</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><div class="icn icn-name"></div></div>
                                <input id="field-name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-company">Company</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><div class="icn icn-company"></div></div>
                                <input id="field-company" name="company" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Company">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-address">Address</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><div class="icn icn-address"></div></div>
                                <input id="field-address" name="address" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Address">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-telephone">Telephone</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><div class="icn icn-telephone"></div></div>
                                <input id="field-telephone" name="telephone" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Telephone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-email">Email</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><div class="icn icn-email"></div></div>
                                <input id="field-email" name="email" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-website">Website</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><div class="icn icn-website"></div></div>
                                <input id="field-website" name="website" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Website">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="field-message">Message</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-addon"><div class="icn icn-message"></div></div>
                                <textarea id="field-message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="form-contact-submit" class="btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="information">
                            <div class="info-title">Send Us A Message</div>
                            <div class="info-text">{{common.send_message_text|safe}}</div>
                            <address>{{common.company}} {{common.address}}</address>
                            <div class="methods">
                                <p>Tel. {{common.telephone_disp}}<br />
                                Email. {{common.email}}<br />
                                {{common.registration}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                      
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.contact .form-control:focus {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(108, 123, 61, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(108, 123, 61, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(108, 123, 61, 0.6);
}
.contact .form-group {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.contact .form-group .input-group-addon {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    line-height: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.contact .form-group .icn {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 59px;
    height: 59px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.contact .form-group input,
.contact .form-group textarea {
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
.contact .form-group input {
    height: 59px;
}
.contact .form-group textarea {
    padding-top: 20px;
    height: 375px;
}
.contact .form-group .icn-name {
    background-image: url('../img/form_name_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group .icn-company {
    background-image: url('../img/form_company_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group .icn-address {
    background-image: url('../img/form_address_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group .icn-telephone {
    background-image: url('../img/form_telephone_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group .icn-address {
    background-image: url('../img/form_address_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group .icn-email {
    background-image: url('../img/form_email_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group .icn-website {
    background-image: url('../img/form_website_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group .icn-message {
    background-image: url('../img/form_message_m.png');
}
.contact .form-group input[type='submit'] {
    padding: 20px 65px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #81be41;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    /* WebKit */
    -o-transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    /* Opera */
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
    /* Standard */
}
.contact .form-group input[type='submit']:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #92cf52;
}
```

Comment: add the tag IE; in witch version of IE ? ; for the picture, edit ant take a look at the toolbar to add it

Comment: No wories, it must be the installation as it worked on two other test computers. Crazy I know!